# Is there any way to combine more than two charts in xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I new to Xlsxwriter. I am trying to combine 3 column charts to a single chart. But not able to do so.

chart_1 ,
chart_2 ,
chart_3 ,

I am trying below :

chart_1.combine(chart_2)

chart_1.combine(chart_3)

But chart_2 is not coming. Is there any way to combine 3 charts in xlsxwriter.

Thanks,
Kshitish

Comment: No. That isn’t possible with XlsxWriter.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way around.?